# Can you make a Azure Data Factory data flow for updating data using a foreign key?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I've tried this a few ways and seem to be blocked.

This is nothing more than a daily ETL process.  What I'm trying to do is to use ADF and pull in a csv as one of my datasets.  With that data I need to update docs in a CosmosDb container, which is the other dataset in this flow.  My data really simple.

- ForeignId string
- Value1 int
- Value2 int
- Value3 int

The Cosmos docs all have these data items and more.  ForeignId is unique in the container and is the partition key.  The docs are a composite dataset that actually have 3 other id fields that would be considered the PK in the system of origin.

When you try and use a data flow UPDATE with this data the validation complains that you have to  map "Id" to use UPDATE.  I have an Id in my document, but it only relates to my collection, not to old, external systems.  I have no choice but to use the ForeignId. I have it flowing using UPSERT but, even though I have the ForeignId mapped between the datasets, I get inserts instead of updates.

Is there something I'm missing or is ADF not set up to sync data based on anything other than the a data item named "id"?  Is there another option ADF aside from the straight-forward approach?  I've read that you can drop updates into the Lookup tasks but that seems like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

The row ID is needed by CosmosDB to know which row to update. It has nothing to do with ADF.

To make this work in ADF, add an Exists transformation in your data flow to see if the row already exists in your collection. Check using the foreign key column in your incoming source data against the existing collection.

If a row is found with that foreign key, then you can the corresponding ID to your metadata, allowing you to include it in your sink.